# How to configure MultiOutputFormat from HCatalog API in spring-hadoop project?

Tags: spring, hadoop, mapreduce, spring-data-hadoop

I was developing a hadoop application. And now I want to migrate it into a spring-hadoop project. The thing is in my mapreduce job. I was using MultiOutputFormat from the HCatalog API as I want to store information on multiple tables. And I can not find any example or document saying how to configure this in Spring hadoop.

Can anyone tell me how can I do this or give me some reference materials? Great thanks.

I was developing a hadoop application. And now I want to migrate it into a spring-hadoop project. The thing is in my mapreduce job. I was using MultiOutputFormat from the HCatalog API as I want to store information on multiple tables. And I can not find any example or document saying how to configure this in Spring hadoop.

Can anyone tell me how can I do this or give me some reference materials? Great thanks.

@Thomas Risberg Hi Thomas, thanks for replying. I understand that in spring hadoop we just need to do the job configuration in the corresponding xml file. Currently, in my application, when setting up the job, I have code like below:

```
ArrayList<OutputJobInfo> tableList = new ArrayList<OutputJobInfo>();
tableList.add(OutputJobInfo.create("database", "request",
partitionValuesRequest));
tableList.add(OutputJobInfo.create("database", "requestdetail",
                partitionValues));
tableList.add(OutputJobInfo.create("database", "jobInfo",
                partitionValues));

List<HCatFieldSchema> requestSchemaList = new ArrayList<HCatFieldSchema>();
requestSchemaList .add(new HCatFieldSchema("type", Type.STRING,
                null));
requestSchemaList .add(new HCatFieldSchema("samplesize",
                Type.INT, null));
requestSchemaList .add(new HCatFieldSchema("userid",
                Type.SMALLINT, null));
configurer.addOutputFormat("request", HCatOutputFormat.class,
                BytesWritable.class, HCatRecord.class);
HCatOutputFormat.setOutput(configurer.getJob("request"),
                tableList.get(0));
HCatOutputFormat.setSchema(configurer.getJob("request"),
                new HCatSchema(requestSchemaList));
......
configurer.configure();
```

This is for me to store information in related tables inside the reducer. So my question would be how can I do the corresponding configuration for the MultiOutputFormat in Spring-hadoop? I check the spring-hadoop.xsd. Can't find any related tabs for this.

Comment: The actual MapReduce job wouldn't change if you use spring-data-hadoop. What would change is how the job is submitted using the Spring context and job support for that. So if you can run your job from the command line you should be able to run the same via a Spring configuration. If you share what you have currently we can provide more details.

Comment: @ThomasRisberg  Hi Thomas, thanks for replying. I upload more details in my question, can you have a look on it again? Thanks.

Comment: We don't have any specific HCatalog support at all. You might be able to extend the JobFactoryBean and set the outputFormat to the fully qualified classname as a String. You would then have to use the Hcatalog JobConfigurer to configure the MultiOutputFormat. I haven't tried this, but it doesn't look impossible.